# Sum between two weeks interval

Tags: r

Suppose I have a daily rain data.frame like this:

```
df.meteoro = data.frame(Dates = seq(as.Date("2017/1/19"), as.Date("2018/1/18"), "days"),
                     rain = rnorm(length(seq(as.Date("2017/1/19"), as.Date("2018/1/18"), "days"))))
```

I'm trying to sum the accumulated rain between a 14 days interval with this code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

df.rain <- df.meteoro %>% 
  mutate(TwoWeeks = round_date(df.meteoro$data, "14 days")) %>%
  group_by(TwoWeeks) %>%
  summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain))
```

The problem is that it isn't starting on 2017-01-19 but on 2017-01-15 and I was expecting my output dates to be:

```
"2017-02-02" "2017-02-16" "2017-03-02" "2017-03-16" "2017-03-30" "2017-04-13"
"2017-04-27" "2017-05-11" "2017-05-25" "2017-06-08" "2017-06-22" "2017-07-06" "2017-07-20"
"2017-08-03" "2017-08-17" "2017-08-31" "2017-09-14" "2017-09-28" "2017-10-12" "2017-10-26"
"2017-11-09" "2017-11-23" "2017-12-07" "2017-12-21" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-18"
```

TL;DR I have a year long daily rain data.frame and want to sum the accumulate rain for the dates above.

Please help.

Comment: Given that you've posted your expected output, can I assume that you are able to get a vector of dates you'd wish to analyse? As I may be able to offer an alternative approach.

Comment: I posted and deleted an answer in which I adapted your use of  round_date. I found inconsistencies in the two-week window that was being returned which made a nonsense of the answer I was posting. This may simply be because the two-week period is not a consecutive window as might be thought. Other posters have answered without using the round_date function, a better and more consistent approach I think.

Comment: @Sam yes I have the vector. I trying to figure out a personalized function to replace round_date()

Comment: @AníbalDeboniNeto Did none of the other answers satisfy?

Comment: @Sam Unfortunately no, because all of them rounds the date and I need to know how much rainfall I got between those specific intervals which was when my measurements happened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of round_date in the way you have shown it will not give you 14-day periods as you might expect. I have taken a different approach in this solution and generated a sequence of dates between your first and last dates and grouped these into 14-day periods then joined the dates to your observations.

```
startdate = min(df.meteoro$Dates)
enddate = max(df.meteoro$Dates)
dateseq = 
  data.frame(Dates = seq.Date(startdate, enddate, by = 1)) %>%
  mutate(group = as.numeric(Dates - startdate) %/% 14) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  mutate(starts = min(Dates))


df.rain <- df.meteoro %>% 
  right_join(dateseq) %>%
  group_by(starts) %>%
  summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain))

head(df.rain)

> head(df.rain)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  starts     sum_rain
  <date>        <dbl>
1 2017-01-19    6.09 
2 2017-02-02    5.55 
3 2017-02-16   -3.40 
4 2017-03-02    2.55 
5 2017-03-16   -0.12
6 2017-03-30    8.95
```

Using a right-join to the date sequence is to ensure that if there are missing observation days that spanned a complete time period you'd still get that period listed in the result (though in your case you have a complete year of dates anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much. Works as I'd like. Just changed mutate(starts = min(Dates)) to mutate(starts = max(Dates)) since I'm looking for the total rainfall by the end of the period.

Comment: Glad you found this solution useful.

Answer (score 0):

`round_date` rounds to the nearest multiple of `unit` (here, 14 days) since some epoch (probably the Unix epoch of 1970-01-01 00:00:00), which doesn't line up with your purpose.

To get what you want, you can do the following:

```
df.rain = df.meteoro %>%
    mutate(days_since_start = as.numeric(Dates - as.Date("2017/1/18")),
           TwoWeeks = as.Date("2017/1/18") + 14*ceiling(days_since_start/14)) %>%
    group_by(TwoWeeks) %>%
    summarise(sum_rain = sum(rain))
```

This computes `days_since_start` as the days since 2017/1/18 and then manually rounds to the next multiple of two weeks.

Comment: After posting I figured out how round_date() works, what I need is a function that doesn't round date, just begins with the first date on the data.frame and follow a vector of dates where it should sum up

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to round to the closest date from the ones you have specified I guess the following will work

```
targetDates<-seq(ymd("2017-02-02"),ymd("2018-01-18"),by='14 days')
df.meteoro$Dates=targetDates[sapply(df.meteoro$Dates,function(x) which.min(abs(interval(targetDates,x))))]
sum_rain=ddply(df.meteoro,.(Dates),summarize,sum_rain=sum(rain,na.rm=T))
```

as you can see not all dates have the same number of observations. Date "2017-02-02" for instance has all the records between "2017-01-19" until "2017-02-09", which are 22 records. From  "2017-02-10" on dates are rounded to "2017-02-16" etc.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a cheat, but assuming each row/observation is a separate day, then why not just group by every 14 rows and sum.

```r
# Assign interval groups, each 14 rows
df.meteoro$my_group <-rep(1:100, each=14, length.out=nrow(df.meteoro))

# Grab Interval Names
my_interval_names <- df.meteoro %>%
  select(-rain) %>% 
  group_by(my_group) %>% 
  slice(1)

# Summarise
df.meteoro %>% 
  group_by(my_group) %>% 
  summarise(rain = sum(rain)) %>% 
  left_join(., my_interval_names)

#> Joining, by = "my_group"
#> # A tibble: 27 x 3
#>    my_group   rain Dates     
#>       <int>  <dbl> <date>    
#>  1        1  3.86  2017-01-19
#>  2        2 -0.581 2017-02-02
#>  3        3 -0.876 2017-02-16
#>  4        4  1.80  2017-03-02
#>  5        5  3.79  2017-03-16
#>  6        6 -3.50  2017-03-30
#>  7        7  5.31  2017-04-13
#>  8        8  2.57  2017-04-27
#>  9        9 -1.33  2017-05-11
#> 10       10  5.41  2017-05-25
#> # ... with 17 more rows
```

Created on 2018-03-01 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).